# can we access any c program editor through java

Tags: java, c, linux, unix, parser-generator

I need to develop a c parser in order to extract the function names, macros and its definitions. my approach was not to start from scratch, just access any c program editors like geany which already parses the functions and macros , 
may be a simple api to this editor will get all my requirements, I have googled it, but most of the solutions are to use javacc, so some other parser ...

As this job is already done by editors, so it would be easy , not taking pain to start with building grammar.

this approach would be simple, but unable to find any such editors which have any apis to access it through java.

Comment: Are you really asking whether Java provides an API for every text editor? I think the short answer is 'No'.

Comment: No, I think he meant to ask if there is at least one.

Comment: I don't know about Java but you could use [Codeworker](http://codeworker.free.fr/)

Comment: yup, i want to whether there is atleast one as @twall said

Comment: If you want a reliable C parser, the job is much harder than what you think. See my answer below.

Comment: @rockyit86 - Is the code you are trying to parse syntactically correct, i.e. has it been through a compiler and has no syntax errors?  Or would it be acceptable to fail (not parse it) if the code has syntax errors? It is *much* easier to parse code which is syntactically correct, or where you can just give up at the first syntax error. You could run a compiler across the code, and refuse to look at the source if it finds errors. Also, would it be acceptable to run the code through the C pre-processor before trying to parse for function names and definitions? That would simplify your parser.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is existing [parser-generator](/questions/tagged/parser-generator)

You could see,

1. [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlr)
2. [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29)
3. [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)
4. [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC)

Comment: thanks for your reply,ya i know this stuff, so i was thinking to get macros and functions by using an api provided to java from any other program editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've already used lex, flex, yacc, bison etc. But nothing can beat Perl for doing it. Moreover Perl regular expressions can be used in Java, PHP.

At least use Perl like regular expression to get it done rather than writing in yacc is very difficult to maintain and which can easily be done in a few lines in Perl or PHP.

Comment: I used perl to build my own lexer because I love regex. But regex can not  parse context-free grammar.

Comment: But @rockyit86's requirement can be mostly met by using Perl.

Comment: thanks but this is not what i wanted, i have already done in java by using regualr expressions, but wanted to know any other simpler approach rather than this,

Comment: another approach would be from object files which i do not want

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to develop a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to customize the GCC compiler for your needs. (MELT is a domain specific language that I developed to easily extend GCC).

The advantage of customizing GCC for your purposes is that you'll work on the exact internal representations of GCC. However, GCC being complex, extending it requires some work (in particular, partly understanding the complex GCC internal representations and passes).

<sup>(It is possible for functions, variables and classes, perhaps not for macros today with GCC 4.7, since GCC preprocessor don't have yet any plugin hooks)</sup>

And I am not sure you are right in believing that `geany` has a complete C parser. I believe it has some regexpr based thing, which e.g. ignores any preprocessor tricks. I don't think that `geany` is aware of e.g. functions or variables created by expanding complex macros (like some GTK implementation macros for instance).

Comment: seems to be very complex, i will try it out, or else fix with my hackish way of doing things, with lots of code, breaks here and there :)

Comment: Indeed it is complex, but *parsing **reliably** C code* is much more **complex** than what you imagine. You could accept simpler ways (like `ctags` is doing) if you don't require a full-fledged C parser. Loosening your requirements is up to you.

Comment: @rockyit86 using ctags or etags is actually a good idea, have you thought about it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several IDE's or programmers-editors with C parsers, written in Java. So getting at them shouldn't be too horrific (famous last words :-)

- [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) which has several books on how to write and use plugins/extensions
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)

to mention just two. They both have active user communities who might be able to help too.

Their C editors, have a pretty good grasp of C syntax because they can fold functions. Eclipse's C editor keeps track of definitions, and I think NetBeans does too.

Personally, if I needed to parse C to get function bodies, and the code is syntactically correct, it wouldn't be too hard to use parser-development-tools. IIRC ANTLR might have a C grammar already.